# error when filling an np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to fill an array with a `for` loop but the results always seem to be the last number to enter

```
import numpy as np
quantity = int (input ("enter amount of data"))
for i in range (quantity):
         value = float (input ("enter value of x >>"))
         x = np.array ([value])

print (x)
```

Comment: That's pretty much working as coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the array *once*:

```
quantity = int(input("enter amount of data"))
arr = np.zeros(quantity, dtype=float)
```

Then fill in individual elements as desired:

```
for i in range(quantity):
    arr[i] = float(input("enter value of x >>"))
```

Comment: "create" may be a better choice than "declare" here. +1 regardless

Comment: hank you men you saved me from a hurry